# Properly updating arrays in component state using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning react and trying to understand how to better deal with updating state of a component with arrays. Here is the function I call on `componentWillMount()` of a component to generate components that I render later in this parent component:

```
  generateThings = () => {
    let newThings = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < this.state.numberOfThings; j++) {
      const pos = this.generatePosition(1, 1);
      const thingComp = <Thing key={j} position={pos} />;
      newThings.push(thingComp);
    }
    this.setState({
      things: newThings
    });
  };
```

I thought a better way would be to `push()` to the state field directly (`this.state.things.push(thingComp);`) instead of the storing in a temp variable which seems messier. But that doesn't seem to trigger a UI update, so I'm guessing this is the way to do it, but i'm not sure.

Comment: You could push to the state directly and use the functional `setState` syntax instead. EG: `this.setState((prevState) => { prevState.things.push(...); return prevState; })`. Just note that mutating state outside of a `setState` call won't trigger an update.

Comment: Duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26253351/4333038

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct.

When you call `setState`, it causes the components to rerender: According to [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state
>
> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

If you need to update/push to the existing `things` array:

```
let things = this.state.things.slice(); // make a copy

//push or do whatever to the array
things.push(thingComp)

this.setState({ things: newThings });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition, if you want, you can set the state without pushing and slicing to a different array.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jn8w8w34n3

`the additional array solution is commented`